# band filtering based on PSD, to filter out frequency domains in r, probably using "buttord" from signal

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet, frequency-analysis

I'm still a novice in R and I read quite a couple of posts and discussions on how to filter out frequency domains in a time series, but none of those quite matched my problem.

I would like to ask for your suggestions about the following:
I calculated wavelet coherence for two annually measured time series and taking a look at the wavelet coherence PSD graph:

[image]

The purple line (i.e. 8 year period) represents the border under which I would like to filter out the frequency domain, but not in the PSD, but in the original input data.

I though about using the butter function from the signal package, but it was overcomplicated for my purposes.

Thus I approached the problem with the bwfilter function of the mFilter package fo pass through the data over the 8 year period which corresponds to 2.37E-7 Hz.

```
name="dta OAK.resid Tair "
adat=read.table(file=paste(name,".csv", sep=""), sep=";", header=T)
dta=adat$ya
highpass <- bwfilter(dta, freq=8,drift=FALSE)
plot(highpass)
```

However, the results do not seem to be correct, because it seems to filter out too much from the data, the trend is too much aligned to the original time series.

Do you have any idea what may have gone wrong? The measurement unit maybe?

Any help is appreciated and if any additional details are needed I am happy to provide them!
Thank you!

The data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0GWyljhqBgKc2NCc3ktVDlaV3c)

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproducible example? And this might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22131410/3710546

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem is that is that I have difficulties finding the point where to start, but I'll try to cook something up. Thank you!