# Inverse continuous wavelet transform

Tags: r, wavelet

Using the `wmtsa` R package, one can perform a continuous wavelet transform (CWT) on a vector of data. Here's an example:

```
library(wmtsa)
x=rnorm(8)
cwt=wavCWT(x=x,wavelet="gaussian2")
```

Where the gaussian2 wavelet refers to the mexican hat wavelet. Through the inverse CWT one should be able to retrieve the exact original data object.

However, I cannot find a function that's able to do so.

Does anyone have any suggestion for a function or how to implement the inverse CWT?

Comment: Does it have to be a CWT or could a DWT be suitable, too?

Comment: @RHertel It has to be a CWT. The inverse DWT is available in the `wavethresh` package, amongst others.

Comment: The `reconstruct()` function of the `wmtsa` package doesn't seem to work for CWT. I looked also at the `Rwave` package, but couldn't find anything that seemed to answer your question.  Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22131410/4770166) helps.