# Truncate a Time-Series in R

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet, truncation

I'm using continuous Morlet wavelet transform (cwt) analysis over a time series by the use of the R-package dplR. The time series corresponds to a 15min data (gam_15min) with length 7968 (corresponding to 83 days of measurements).

I have the following output:

```
cwtGamma=morlet(gam_15min,x1=seq_along(gam_15min),p2=NULL,dj=0.1,siglvl=0.95)

    str(cwtGamma)
List of 9
 $ y     : Time-Series [1:7968] from 1 to 1993: 672 674 673 672 672 ...
 $ x     : int [1:7968] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ wave  : cplx [1:7968, 1:130] -0.00332+0.0008i 0.00281-0.00181i -0.00194+0.00234i ...
 $ coi   : num [1:7968] 0.73 1.46 2.19 2.92 3.65 ...
 $ period: num [1:130] 1.03 1.11 1.19 1.27 1.36 ...
 $ Scale : num [1:130] 1 1.07 1.15 1.23 1.32 ...
 $ Signif: num [1:130] 0.000382 0.001418 0.005197 0.018514 0.062909 ...
 $ Power : num [1:7968, 1:130] 1.17e-05 1.11e-05 9.26e-06 7.09e-06 5.54e-06 ...
 $ siglvl: num 0.95
```

In my analysis I want to truncate the time-series (I suppose $wave) by removing 1 period length in the beginning and 1 period length at the end. how do I do that? maybe its easy but I'm seeing how... Thanks

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22131410/3710546
`wt` is your `cwtGamma$wave` and `dial` is your `cwtGamma$Scale`. You need to remove values in both `Re(cwtGamma$wave)` and `cwtGamma$Scale`.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it!