# perfect reconstruction of wavelet transform using CWT

Tags: matlab, wavelet, wavelet-transform

If I perform a standard wavelet transform and then perform the inverse, I was expecting to get the original signal back:

```
% dummy series:
Fs = 1e3;
t = 0:1/Fs:1;
x = exp(cos(2*pi*32*t).*(t>=0.1 & t<0.3) + sin(2*pi*64*t).*(t>0.7));

% perform default transform and inverse
wt=cwt(x)
rx=icwt(wt)

% plot
plot(t,x,t,rx)
```

Apart from the offset, the flat period signals are distorted.
[image: original series and reconstruction from cwt and icwt]
It seems to be possible to perform a transform/inverse and have something close to the identity function, as here [Wavelet reconstruction of time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131080/wavelet-reconstruction-of-time-series-r) , but reading the tutorials/help for `cwt` I do not see how to achieve this.

Comment: It depends on the wavelet whether this is possible or not. Most wavelets are not orthogonal and do not provide complete decompositions.

Comment: Is there any reason why not use the DWT?

Comment: Well the DWT works (i.e. invariant inverse) but I wanted to  use the cross-power between two series to construct a wavelet filter to retain the common signals between two similar timeseries, and I didn't see any option for that in DWT, only in the continuous wavelet package CWT.

Answer (score 1):

[The matlab documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/gs/continuous-and-discrete-wavelet-transforms.html) explains that the CWT is not the best choice for perfect reconstruction. However if you want to compare different bands as signals with the same size as the original, you can use the [MODWT](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/modwt.html) (or the shift-invariant DWT by [cycle-spinning](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/wavelet/mw/wavelet-ex26083760-1-d-cycle-spinning), sometimes calles *à trous*).